# how to redirect other users asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem and i think its have to do with sessions. (at least i want it to be related to sessions because i need to use sessions),

Suppose i have a list of names of people logged in, on my site .

I want that  once i press someone's name, that he and I will get a game board. (No confirmation at the moment ..).
Now how do i get the game board , it's obvious. **but, how to make that the other  user will get one .. ?**(the user that i chose from the list).

The other user, he is like a passive user, he suddenly getting a game board.
someone understands?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need some COMET/push technology. You may take a look at [`SignalR`](http://signalr.net/) which would allow you to push contents to specified clients. Basically all clients will subscribe to notifications from the server and when a particular request comes from an administrator you could then send notification to the selected clients.

Comment: Perhaps, there is a solution without having to download any software?

Comment: Yes, there is, you may go ahead and read the WebSockets specification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket and write your own server but bear in mind that this might be quite a lot of work. That's why people created servers such as SignalR that will handle all the heavy lifting for you.